# GUI status in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

EDIT: Made some changes based on feedback in comments.

I am trying to use a statusTextF function to show a WAIT/READY message on python GUI.

I have defined, at the beginning, when the GUI is drawn.

```
statusText = True
```

and then call the following when i want it to wait:

```
statusText = False
```

I call statusText as a global variable everywhere I use it, and I have the statusTextF function as shown below:

```
def statusTextF():
    if statusText == True:
        statusTitle = tk.Label(root,text="READY")
        statusTitle.config(font=statusFont,bg="light green")
        statusX = 500
        statusY = 450
        statusTitle.place(x=statusX,y=statusY)
        separation = 45
    else:
        statusTitle = tk.Label(root,text="WAIT")
        statusTitle.config(font=statusFont,bg="light red")
        statusX = 500
        statusY = 450
        statusTitle.place(x=statusX,y=statusY)
        separation = 45
```

I am seeing `'READY'` all the time though.

What could be wrong?

Now, it doesn't display anything, and also I get a light red is unknown colour error.

Comment: `if True:` is always true so it will always execute only this part.

Comment: There is no possible way for that code to produce the "WAIT" text - `if True:` cannot possibly be false!  And Tkinter doesn't really get along with threads anyway, you should do all GUI operations from the main thread only.  (Changing the status via a thread is pointless, anyway - it probably takes longer to launch the thread than to actually change the text of the widget!)

Comment: `tkiner` doesn't support multithreading in the sense that only one thread, usually the main one, can use it. That means that threads must use other means to communicate to the main thread. This is usually done vai a `Queue` and making use of the universal [`after`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) widget method to periodically check the queue in the main thread and update the GUI accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I see that I have missed the True condition issue. What is a better way to send a command to change the text - maybe change another global variable and run an if test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demonstration of how to do something like you want. It doesn't use a `Queue` for communication between the main GUI thread and the status updating thread since the amount of information being exchanged between them is so minimal. It instead uses a `threading.Lock` to control access to a global variable shared between them. Note that it's also implicitly being used to protect updates to the `separation` global.

Using a [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue) to exchange the information ought be fairly easy to implement — should you need one for some reason — since they don't need a separate `Lock` because they implement "all the required locking semantics" interally.

Note: I've tried to (mostly) follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to make it fairly readable — which I *strongly* suggest you read (and also follow).

```
import random
import time
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import threading

class StatusUpdater(threading.Thread):
#    # Not really needed since it doesn't do anything except call superclass ctor here.
#    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Initialize base class constructor.

    def run(self):
        global status_flag_lock, status_flag  # Must declare these to change their values.

        while True:
            # Randomly update status_flag.
            value = random.randint(0, 100)
            with status_flag_lock:
                status_flag = bool(value % 2)  # True if odd number.
            time.sleep(.5)  # Pause updating for a little while.


def statusTextF():
    global status_flag_lock, separation  # Must declare these to change their values.

    with status_flag_lock:
        if status_flag:
            statusTitle.config(text="READY", bg="light green")
            separation = 45
        else:
            statusTitle.config(text="WAIT", bg="pink")
            separation = 55

    root.after(250, statusTextF)  # Continue the polling.


status_flag_lock = threading.Lock()  # To control concurrent access.

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x600')

STATUS_FONT = tkFont.Font(family='Courier', size=8)
STATUS_X, STATUS_Y = 500, 450

status_flag = True
separation = 45

statusTitle = tk.Label(root, text="UNKNOWN", font=STATUS_FONT, bg="gray50")
statusTitle.place(x=STATUS_X, y=STATUS_Y)

status_updater = StatusUpdater(daemon=True)
status_updater.start()  # Start updating of status flag.
root.after(250, statusTextF)  # Start polling status every 250 millisecs.
root.mainloop()
```